# Convolving two signals

Tags: signals, signal-processing, convolution

> Calculate the convolution of the following signals (your answer will be in the form of an equation):
>    `h[n] = δ[n-1] + δ[n+1], x[n] = δ[n-a] + δ[n+b]`

I'm lost as to what I do with h and x. Do I simply multiply them? h[n]*x[n]? I programmed convolution with several types of blurs and edge detectors, but I don't see how to translate that knowledge to this problem. Please help!

Comment: If this is homework please remember to mark it with the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is an operation distinct from multiplication. If `h[n] = delta[n-a]` represents an impulse at n=a, then the convolution of h and any function `f[n]` is equal to `conv(h,f) = f[n-a]`, and you should be able to determine the answer to your question through superposition, since convolution and addition are both linear operators.

Answer (score 0):

The convolution of h and x (h*x) will be something like h*x = SUM h[n-q]*x[n], where the sum is performed over all possible q's depending on the size of h. If h and x are infinite then the sum goes from -INF to +INF.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, (and more so if you are unsure about convolution), it is convenient to do the [convolution graphically](http://cnx.org/content/m11539/latest/), to grap the basics and relate that to the analytical formula.